# KDE Konsole reacts on mouse clicks in a strange way

Tags: kde, console

From time to time my KDE Konsole goes crazy, every time I click in it with the mouse it print out garbage characters :) It's not really annoying, I just close it, but I'm curious why this happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me guess: do you mean the effect that you get when you execute the
following command?

```
printf '\e[?1000h'
```

What happens is the following. There are two kinds of
programs running in a terminal emulator like konsole:
those that rely on the basic mouse handling offered by the terminal
program (e.g.: left button selects, middle button pastes), and those
that want to do their own interpretation of mouse events. Most programs,
such as bash, do the former, midnight commander (mc) is an example of
the latter. If a program wants to interpret mouse events by itself,
it sends a certain "escape sequence" (like the one above) to konsole,
so that konsole sends back the coordinates of the mouse whenever
a button is pressed; when the program stops, it sends another
"escape sequence" to konsole, so that konsole returns to its normal mode.

What happened in your case is that konsole received the escape
sequence without a cooperating program running. There are several
possible reasons:

- A badly programmed tool switched the mouse mode and then
  crashed without switching back.
- You dumped some binary data, e.g., some executable program
  to the screen, which contained the mouse switching escape sequence.
- You misspelled some escape sequence, that was supposed to,
  e.g., change the font or the background colour in your prompt
  and accidentally got the mouse switching escape sequence.

The same applies to other terminal emulator programs like xterm or
gnome-terminal. (The mouse switching escape sequence was introduced in xterm; both konsole and gnome-terminal copied it.)
By the way, it's usually not necessary to close konsole if something
like this happens. You can use the `reset` command to return to the normal mode.

Comment: Yes, exactly this :) Excellent answer!

Comment: TL;DR - use the `reset` command to return to normal mode